# Associating a class object with a variable changes the class object

Tags: ruby

Please explain how this can happen:

```
a = Class.new(StandardError).new
# => #<#<Class:0x007fa3af1d24a0>: #<Class:0x007fa3af1d24a0>>
a.class.name
# => nil
AError = a.class
# => AError
a.class.name
# => "AError"
```

Is the class object assignment handled as a special case in the language/vm? How is the class object aware that it has or has not been assigned to a constant?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is intended behaviour / special case. When you create a class with `Class.new`, it doesn't have a name initially. It copies the name of the first constant it's assigned to.

> How is the class object aware that it has or has not been assigned to a constant?

Ruby VM knows everything.

Comment: "When you create a class dynamically" is not accurate as a condition for a nameless class. You can statically create a nameless class.

Comment: @sawa: example?

Comment: Nah, it’s a matter of what we would call “statically” in Ruby.

Comment: What is your definition of dynamically/statically?

Comment: @sawa: this is terminology nitpicking. I don't consider this a "static definition". Compare this to the "normal" class syntax, where classes spring to life upon mere parsing of the code. In a compiled language this would be done at compile stage, and this is the closest thing we have to a compile stage. With `Class.new` you have to actively evaluate the line. This is "dynamic" in my book.

Comment: I suppose by "normal class syntax", you mean `class Foo; end`. But how can you create the class `Foo` without evaluating that code? Just by parsing and stopping there, you don't get `Foo` defined. How is that different from `Class.new` written in the main context?

Comment: Moreover, whatever your notion of dynamic/static may be, my point is that mentioning to such terminology only distracts the reader from the crucial point. The only thing you needed to mention is that a class is not given a name until it is assigned to a constant.

Comment: @sawa: I suppose I do have inconsistent notion of "dynamic". I'll meditate on that. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you be more specific than "Ruby VM knows everything"? :)

Comment: @ÁkosVandra: yeah, that was an "easy" answer. I'll look up the code that does this when I have a bit of free time.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev much appreciated, I tried to search for it, but could not find it. Is it also possible to hook into this for my own purposes as well?

Comment: @ÁkosVandra: if you come up with a way to utilize this feature, then by all means :) I personally can't imagine how it could be useful.

Comment: I mean not with classes.... I have a bunch of code like `SomeConstant = Something.define { name 'SomeConstant' ; other_stuff }... getting rid of that name definition would be handy.